# Connexion:flask api throwing Cannot resolve operationId "people.welcome"! Import error was "No module named 'people'"

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, connexion

this is my project structure:
[image]

This is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import connexion

app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir="./")
app.add_api("swagger.yaml")
```

this is my people.py

```
from .app import app


def welcome():
    return "Hello World!"
```

this is my init.py

```
from .app import app
from .people import welcome
```

This is my swagger.yaml file

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: "RP Flask REST API"
  description: "An API about people and notes"
  version: "1.0.0"

servers:
  - url: "/api"

paths:
  /hello:
    get:

      operationId: people.welcome
      tags:
        - "People"
      summary: "Read the list of people"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Successfully read people list"
```

While running the flask app i am getting the below error:

```
File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\connexionTest\venv\lib\site-packages\connexion\resolver.py", line 71, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
raise ResolverError(msg, sys.exc_info())
connexion.exceptions.ResolverError: <ResolverError: Cannot resolve operationId "people.welcome"! Import error was "No module named 'people'">
```

I tried to give absolute path/relative path to the operation id but still nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

#### @connexion 2.14.1

Connexion does not handle that `__init__.py` very well. These steps should solve it:

1. Remove your `__init__.py` (Connexion will resolve packages within `operationId` regardless);
2. Connexion creates the Flask `app` for you, no need to import Flask directly.

Your `app.py` should look like this:

```
import connexion

app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir="./")
app.add_api("swagger.yaml")

app = app.app
```

And your `people.py` does not require any import at the moment:

```
def welcome():
    return "Hello World!"
```